# Apple Mach O Linker error. while add framework sdk file(libpaymentsdk.a) file into xcode .xcworkspace in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, payment

While I adding `libpaymentsdk.a` file into my Xcode project it shows **Apple Mach O Linker error**. Currently, I'm using `xcworkspace`. While adding the same SDK into the new project which doesn't have `xcworkspace` work fine.
Same situation while adding any framework.

Comment: could you post your complete log of Apple Mach O Linker error.

Comment: please check on below image.